# vaadin7: calling navigator from a view renders a stackoverflow error

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Given a Main UI which encapsulates a vaadin Navigator, i need to call it from a search view so as to display search results in another view:

1) Main Ui

```
Navigator nav = new Navigator(this, content)
        nav.addView("/search", new SearchView())
...
```

So everything works fine (with other views), until  i implement the search view:

```
private static final String VIEW_SEARCH= "search"
        private static final String VIEW_RESULTS = "searchResults"
```

in the constructor:
public SearchView() {

```
UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().addView(VIEW_SEARCH, new SearchView())
UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().addView(VIEW_RESULTS, new SearchResultsView())
```

which renders a stack overflow error:

```
*********************************************************
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
2013-12-21 19:47:00,772 ERROR [DefaultErrorHandler] - 
com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager$RpcInvocationException: Unable to invoke method click in com.vaadin.shared.ui.button.ButtonServerRpc
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:170)
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:207)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:102)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException: Invocation of method buttonClick in com.webvibes.conquest.ui.KMUI$2 failed.
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:528)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:969)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:368)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.webvibes.conquest.ui.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.groovy:43)
    at com.webvibes.conquest.ui.SearchView.<init>(SearchView.groovy:43)
```

The goal here is pretty basic, the search view handles a Button which opens up a new view for the results with parameters:

```
KMUI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo(VIEW_RESULTS)
```

Thanks for any help.

*** UPDATE:

Well, it seems that putting

```
UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().addView(VIEW_SEARCH, new SearchView())
UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().addView(VIEW_RESULTS, new SearchResultsView())
```

directly into the main UI does the job,

but, in that case i miss the results constructor to send the results... what is the best way to send results (HashMap) to the reults view:

```
No signature of method: com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator.navigateTo() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.HashMap) values: [/searchResults, [total:0, hits:org.compass.core.impl.DefaultCompassDetachedHits@340f9d23, ...]]
Possible solutions: navigateTo(java.lang.String)

        KMUI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo(VIEW_RESULTS, res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the session to pass parameter to another view. 
Check this link for an example:

[Setting and reading session attributes](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Setting%20and%20reading%20session%20attributes)